# initialize js after bs ajax modal has loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Need to re-initialize js AFTER the bs3 ajax modal has loaded. In this example the checkboxes are not being styled by uniform because the modal loaded after the js.  So, I need to initialize the js after the modal has loaded to show proper styling on those elements.

**Main :**

```
<a href="/modals/m_comp_settings.php?id=12" data-target="#modal-ajax" data-toggle="modal">Change settings</a>

<!-- ajax remote modal entry -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-ajax" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <img src="/assets/img/ajax-modal-loading.gif" alt="" class="loading">
</div>
<!-- END MODALS -->
```

**m_comp_settings.php (the modal) :**
The modal is properly formatted of course, but here is an example of an input which should be styled with uniform.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="hide" checked disabled> test</label>
```

**What I assumed :**

```
$('#modal-ajax').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
    App.initAjax();
});
```

I figured this would work.  shown.bs.modal should fire after the modal is loaded and then I re-initialize uniform through App.initAjax();  This call basically initializes some core handlers for my site.  I know this works properly as I use it after ajax load calls.  For example :

```
$('#show_comps').load('/process/p_show_comps.php', function() {
    $('#show_comps').fadeIn('slow');
    // reinit js handlers on loaded content
    App.initAjax(); // reinitializes the core stuff
    // show success toast
    toastr.info("'<b>"+response.computer_name+"</b>' was deleted from your account.");
})
```

EDIT
**Additional testing :**

Using the below code the alert shows after the click and before the modal appears.  Changing this to 'shown' which according to docs should be after it has 'shown' on the screen and nothing happens.  What gives?

```
$('#modal-ajax').on('show.bs.modal', function () { 
    console.log();
    alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: So, is your issue that the `shown.bs.modal` event isn't firing when you want it to or that `App.initAjax()` is getting called, but isn't accomplishing what you need?  If you don't know the answer to that, then put a `console.log()` in the event handler and see if it's getting called.

Comment: it is not even firing... just to make sure I also have a handler attached to $('#modal-ajax').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() and console.log() returns '(nothing to output)' as expected on modal close.

Comment: Then you need to examine the library that you're using that is supposed to create that event and see what you're doing wrong.  That is a custom event so it's not directly created by the browser itself, some third party code would have to create the event.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with this today, trying to interact with content loaded via `ajax` into the `Bootstrap` model on the `shown.bs.modal` event. As far as I can tell, that since the `ajax` is (by definition) **asynchronous**, the modal is being shown **before** the `ajax` loaded content has been ... loaded. I looked in the `Bootstrap` js file and I don't see any indication the shown event **waits** for the ajax to complete. So you can't rely on the `shown.bs.modal` to interact with the `ajax` loaded content.

I think you'd need to rely on a `function` called after your `ajax` is loaded, which would probably mean writing a wrapper `function` to interact with the `Bootstrap` modal, load your `ajax`, and then perform whatever actions you need.